# Makefile generated file is not copied

Tags: makefile

The situation is quite simple. I have a set of files (*.extA) and one (*.extB). From all the *.extB I'm generating .extA with a shell script. Then I want to copy all *.extA files to an install directory. This doesn't happen for the generated file.

```
convert:
    ./convertFile.sh

DATA = $(wildcard ./data/*.extA)
TARGET := $(patsubst ./data/%.extA, ../install/data/%.extA, $(DATA))
install: $(TARGET)
../install/data/%.extA: ./data/%.extA
    cp -f $< $@
```

As a result DATA does not contain myfile.extA and cp does not copy it. As a brute force to fix the problem I changed DATA to:

```
DATA = $(wildcard ./data/*.extA) ./data/targetFile.extA
```

While this solves the problem, I have a hard time believing that this can't be done in a more elegant way. What if I'll have a 100 generated files? What am I missing in this case? How can I make sure that DATA is not evaluated until the implicit rule is done? I also tried to use a rule called convert but I can't make the variable depend on rules...

What are my options?

Thanks!

Update:
the convertFile.sh script picks up all *.extB files and creates extA files from them. This actually does a base64 encode on certain entries in the file. So those two files are NOT interchangeable.
Changed the conversion rule back to the original, because that was just for a minimal sample :). Now here's the scenario:

```
01.extA
02.extA
03.extA
...
10.extA
11.extB
12.extB
...
98.extB
99.extA
```

All those *.extB files are converted to extA using make convert. However as DATA does not contain any of these files they're not copied in the install target.

In an ideal world I want to achieve the following:
Convert the extB files to extA files -> Copy all axtA files to install (including the generated ones)

clean rule erases all converted extA files because they should never end up in the repository but this is just for extra information so I can't do a prepocess convert and use make for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know what `*.extA` will be created:

```
convert:
    ./convertFile.sh

install: convert
    install -d data/*.extA ../install/data/

.PHONY: convert install
```

If you can determine the names of `*.extA` (before running `./convertFile.sh`) you can replace `install: convert` to `install: names_of_extA`.

Comment: Two questions: Why use `mkdir -p` instead of `install -D -d`?  And why hide these commands with `@`?

Comment: I can't include any extB directly because they have an incorrect format. I'll update my post.

Comment: @TobySpeight Q1: I'm using FreeBSD and in its `Makefile`s are defined several macros without creating directories (`COPYTREE_SHARE`, `COPYTREE_BIN`, etc.) and should create directories with `mkdir`. Q2: it's optional.

Comment: I made it overly complicated... Thank you , this works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is probably about right.  The reason is that the `$(wildcard )` is expanded when the Makefile is processed, which is before you create `./data/myfile.extA`, so it won't appear in the expansion.

It's hard to know what other approaches might apply, since there's so much missing from the Makefile (I'm guessing `INSTALL` is derived somehow from `DATA` or `TARGET`, but you've not shown us that bit, for example).

Comment: You were right, I completely misstyped that bit. That's TARGET not INSTALL just caps over and type the rule name. Other than that there's no other info in my Makefile. Only the names has been changed.

Comment: You suggested you might have 100 generated files, but it's not clear whether they would be generated using a pattern rule; I also can't tell whether there are files in `TARGET` that you don't generate using this Makefile.